# web scraping - TimeoutException problem (investing.com)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to do web scraping (one page of investing.com) using Selenium.
To extract data from a fixed period of time, I have to set a date range and hit the Apply button to start scraping,
The code works until the date range, but after that, I keep getting a TimeException error from applying button code.

here is my code

## It was successful to set range. (Data range)

date_range_picker = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id="picker"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '01/01/2020 - 12/31/2020')", date_range_picker)

########Problem part##########

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
apply_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[@id="applyBtn"]')))
apply_button.click()

####################
#I tried to expand more time instead of 30, but still it doesn't work.